# Oracle stored procedure call with provided/default parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Suppose I have the following Oracle stored procedure signature:

```
procedure my_procedure(parameter_1 varchar2, parameter_2 varchar2 default 'someDefaultValue', parameter_3 varchar2 default 'anotherDefaultValue', parameter_4 varchar2 default 'oneMoreDefaultValue')
```

If I make the following call to this stored procedure:

```
BEGIN my_procedure('one','two'); END;
```

I'm pretty sure that, inside the stored procedure, `parameter_1` will hold the value `one`.

However, what variable will hold the value `two`?

Thanks!

Comment: `parameter_2` will hold value 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are passing a value for second parameter as two, second parameter will take it as a passing value. See the following example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure (
    parameter_1     VARCHAR2,
    parameter_2     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'someDefaultValue',
    parameter_3     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'anotherDefaultValue',
    parameter_4     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'oneMoreDefaultValue'
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('first param ' || parameter_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('second param ' || parameter_2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('third param ' || parameter_3);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('fourth param ' || parameter_4);
END;
```

and execute procedure by

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 30000;

BEGIN
    my_procedure ('one', 'two');
END;
```

and output

```
first param one
second param two
third param anotherDefaultValue
fourth param oneMoreDefaultValue
```

Comment: Ah! Ok, so the parameters are filled with as many values are provided in the method call, from left to right. Now I get it. Cool example. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if values are passed as arguments to method, then default value is neglected.

Comment: @JesúsZazueta: if you don't use positional parameters, but named ones, you can also supply values for any parameter and don't need to worry about the order of them: `my_procedure(parameter_1 => 'foo', parameter_4 => 'bar');` will work just as well